# calculate time difference between two dates in seconds using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am calculating sum of total records between 6 and 59 sec, not working.

```
sum(
    case trunc((d.start_date-s.end_date)*24*60*60)
    when between 6 and 59 then 1
    end) as onemin
from employee;
```

Comment: `case when trunc((d.start_date-s.end_date)*24*60*60) between 6 and 59 then 1 end`

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? A proper error message and desired behavior would be helpful.

Comment: What do you expect if the difference is greater than 1 Minute?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The error is a minor typographic mistake; as jarlh pointed out all they need to do to fix it is to move the `WHEN` keyword to before the `TRUNC` function and (probably) swap `end_date` and `start_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to move the condition after the `when` keyword:

```
sum( 
    case when trunc((d.start_date-s.end_date)*24*60*60) between 6 and 59 then 1 end
) as onemin
```

You might also want to express the condition as follows, avoiding the need to apply a function to each and every record (this might be more efficient):

```
sum (
    case when
        d.start_date - s.end_date >= 6 / 24 / 60 / 60
        and d.start_date - s.end_date < 60 / 24 / 60 / 60 -- or 1 / 24 / 60
    then 1 end
) onemin
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one syntax error in the [`CASE` expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm).

```sql
CASE expression
WHEN comparison_expression THEN return_expression
WHEN comparison_expression THEN return_expression
WHEN comparison_expression THEN return_expression
END
```

Is valid syntax when the `comparison_expression`s are singular items. If you want to use a range with the `BETWEEN` keyword then you need to use the syntax:

```sql
CASE
WHEN expression BETWEEN comparison_expression AND comparison_expression
  THEN return_expression
END
```

So you could either use:

```sql
CASE trunc((d.start_date-s.end_date)*24*60*60)
WHEN  6 THEN 1
WHEN  7 THEN 1
WHEN  8 THEN 1
-- ...
WHEN 59 THEN 1
END
```

or, simpler, you could move the `WHEN` keyword before the `TRUNC` function:

```sql
CASE
WHEN TRUNC( (d.start_date - s.end_date)*24*60*60 )
     BETWEEN 6 AND 59
THEN 1
END
```

This still probably won't give you the answer you want as the `end_date` is likely to the a larger value than the `start_date` so the resulting difference in subtracting the former from the latter will be a negative number. The simple fix for that is to swap the terms:

```sql
CASE
WHEN TRUNC( (s.end_date - d.start_date)*24*60*60 )
     BETWEEN 6 AND 59
THEN 1
END
```

However, this might be more performant as it may allow you to use the indexes (whereas wrapping the difference in `TRUNC` will require a function-based index):

```sql
CASE
WHEN (s.end_date - d.start_date)*24*60*60 >=  6
AND  (s.end_date - d.start_date)*24*60*60 <  60
THEN 1
END
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=65bd7b45da1a4a0be3faab2f61ed4f1c)